# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Tags: java, indexing

I am getting a weird exception code.

The code that I am trying to use is as follows:

```
 do
 {
  //blah blah actions.

     System.out.print("\nEnter another rental (y/n): ");
     another = Keyboard.nextLine();
 }
 while (Character.toUpperCase(another.charAt(0)) == 'Y');
```

The error code is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
 at Store.main(Store.java:57)
```

Line 57 is the one that starts "while...".

Please help, this is driving me batty!

Comment: Another is instantiated to "Y". I have had the same error even if it is Instantiated to "YES".

Comment: Chente - this error can **only** happen if `another` is the empty string.  Check your assertion more closely (ideally with a debugger so you can see exactly what's going on) and/or implement Itay's suggestions and see how the issue goes away.

Answer (score 8):

That will happen if `another` is the empty string.

We don't know what the `Keyboard` class is, but presumably its `nextLine` method can return an empty string... so you should check for that too.

Answer (score 5):

Fix:

```
do
{
   //blah blah actions.

   System.out.print("\nEnter another rental (y/n): ");
   another = Keyboard.nextLine();
}
while (another.length() == 0 || Character.toUpperCase(another.charAt(0)) == 'Y');
```

Or even better:

```
do
{
   //blah blah actions.

   System.out.print("\nEnter another rental (y/n): ");
   while(true) {
      another = Keyboard.nextLine();
      if(another.length() != 0)
        break;
   }
}
while (Character.toUpperCase(another.charAt(0)) == 'Y');
```

This second version will not print "Enter another rental" if you accidentally press Enter.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is an eloquent solution!